# Bitbake build failed with configure: error: could not find Python headers

Tags: python, yocto, openembedded

I am currently building a yocto image for RPI3 with Yocto poky.Unfortunately the build failed with the following error:

ERROR: Task 1797 (/work/rpi/meta-openembedded/meta-python/recipes-devtools/python/python-dbus_1.2.0.bb, do_configure) failed with exit code '1'

This is a part of the error-log:

```
| checking for python script directory... Traceback (most recent call last):
|   File "<string>", line 22, in <module>
|   File "/work/rpi/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/sysconfig.py", line 22, in <module>
|     PREFIX = os.path.normpath(sys.prefix).replace( os.getenv("BUILD_SYS"), os.getenv("HOST_SYS") )
| TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object
| ${libdir}/python2.7/site-packages
| checking for python extension module directory... Traceback (most recent call last):
|   File "<string>", line 22, in <module>
|   File "/work/rpi/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/sysconfig.py", line 22, in <module>
|     PREFIX = os.path.normpath(sys.prefix).replace( os.getenv("BUILD_SYS"), os.getenv("HOST_SYS") )
| TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object
| ${libdir}/python2.7/site-packages
| checking for Python headers using /work/rpi/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/python-native/python-config --includes... Traceback (most recent call last):
|   File "/work/rpi/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/python-native/python-config", line 6, in <module>
|     from distutils import sysconfig
|   File "/work/rpi/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/sysconfig.py", line 22, in <module>
|     PREFIX = os.path.normpath(sys.prefix).replace( os.getenv("BUILD_SYS"), os.getenv("HOST_SYS") )
| TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object
| failed, will try another way
| checking for Python headers in /work/rpi/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr and /work/rpi/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr... -I/work/rpi/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/include/python2.7
| checking whether those headers are sufficient... no
| configure: error: could not find Python headers
| NOTE: The following config.log files may provide further information.
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| NOTE: /work/rpi/poky/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/python-dbus/1.2.0-r0/build/config.log
| ERROR: configure failed
| ERROR: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /work/rpi/poky/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/python-dbus/1.2.0-r0/temp/log.do_configure.4034)
ERROR: Task 1797 (/work/rpi/meta-openembedded/meta-python/recipes-devtools/python/python-dbus_1.2.0.bb, do_configure) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 2561 tasks of which 2560 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
No currently running tasks (1401 of 2591)

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /work/rpi/meta-openembedded/meta-python/recipes-devtools/python/python-dbus_1.2.0.bb, do_configure
Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

Anybody a guess?
Thx.

Comment: Did you install all packages required for running yocto on your host machine?

Comment: Yes I did. Finally I bypassed the error by skip the installation of dbus, because it's actually not required.

Comment: Not really the answer I was looking for, but is work for me too. Also on the RPi3